# What can I do with shredded wheat shreds?

Tags: culinary-uses, breakfast, wheat

At the bottom of the box of shredded wheat squares, there's quite a bit of 'loose' shredded wheat; it used to be in cereal form and is now just loose.

What interesting recipes or dish modifications can you suggest?

One idea was a sort of crisp/struedel topping, (mix with butter and bake on top of a fruit dessert)

Answer (score 6):

There's a middle-eastern dish called [Kataife](http://baking.about.com/od/greekdesserts/r/kataifeshredded.htm) that uses loose shredded wheat rehydrated with sugar, walnuts, cinnamon and a few other things. My grandma makes it and it is fantastic.

Comment: Interesting proposition. Normally, this dish is made with a kind of dry baked noodles created specifically for this purpose, but I guess this variation can work too.

Answer (score 4):

I have to say I haven't done this since i was about 10 but when I was a child I used to make [chocolate nests](http://www.deliciousmagazine.co.uk/recipes/chocolate-nests) out of them.

Comment: Most cereals can be done up in this way, the most common being the ubiquitous rice krispie cakes, and corn flake cakes.  But the shredded wheat version looks the most nest like by far.

Comment: At school we had rice crispy cakes made from a soft toffee/caramel that would be good to experiment with too, the only recipes I've found since have marshmallow which isn't quite the same

Answer (score 3):

You could also use them in place of bread crumbs when, for example, coating [chicken breasts](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/topics/show/152342-shredded-wheat-baked-chicken).

You could also use them in [muffins](http://recipeland.com/search?q=shredded+wheat+muffins).

There's a whole list of shredded wheat recipes [here](http://community.tasteofhome.com/forums/t/76070.aspx?PageIndex=3) and [here](http://recipes.sparkpeople.com/great-recipes.asp?food=shredded+wheat).

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use as an ingredient in bread.  [Nova Scotia Brown Bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11198/my-grandmothers-brown-bread) utilizes molasses, shortening, and in some recipes that I've seen, shredded wheat.  For example, you could use the equivalent of two pieces in [this recipe](http://www.cooks.com/rec/view/0,1818,158173-234194,00.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the cinnamon shredded wheat left over, you could use it on french toast right after you dip the bread in the egg/milk mixture, and before you put it in the pan.

Another way to recycle it is to make a snack dessert with walnuts, loose cinnamon shredded wheat, cocoa, and peanut butter. Mix it all up and add powder sugar at the end (Shake it in a bag is easiest. Just like you would make puppy chow- a common sweet snack.)

Answer (score 1):

I use the unsweetened crumbs in my meatloaf.

Answer (score 1):

With a little planning you can add it to most brownie mixes with great results.  You might have to add an extra egg and some milk to the mixture and bake it a little longer, but that's a heck of a lot easier than trying to make something from scratch.  I made some brownies with about two or three cups of crumbs, took them to work the next day and everybody loved them.  Not only did the shredded wheat crumbs increase the volume of the mix, it also gave it a little more texture, sort of like a coconut mixture.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use it as crust on some desserts like pudding or cheesecake.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Seasoned Advice way of saying thank you.

Comment: Indeed, no need to say thanks in answers - but the rest of this is still an answer!